# What is the relation between diameter of (Cn) and its complement ~Cn. Is it true that diam(Cn) ≥ diam(~Cn)?

Tags: graph-theory

Cn is a cycle graph and ~Cn is its complement.
As far as I know the diameter for complement of any cycle graph would result in a graph with a diameter of 2

Comment: yes it is a cycle graph and ~cn is its complement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $C_n$ has a diameter of $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. For $n \geq 5$ you can prove that the diameter of the complement of $C_n$ is 2. $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \geq 2$ for all $n \geq 5$ (and equality only holds when $n=5$) so your statement is true for $n \geq 5$. Not that the complement of $C_3$ is disconnected, as is the complement of $C_4$ so the statement is not true for $n \leq 4$.

Comment: I think that for a complement the diameter is always 2. what do you think

Comment: As I said in my answer, when $n \geq 5$ the diameter of ~$C_n$ is indeed 2 and you can prove this fairly easily. Just think about what pair of vertices are/are not adjacent in ~$C_n$ and argue that they must have a common neighbour.